# Lazy loading of Module routing path issue. Error when navigating to http://localhost:4200/products

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-router

**AppRoutingMoudle**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

const ROUTES : Routes = [
    /*
        ProductModule (defined in the feature module) is loaded lazily when navigating to /products
    */
   {path: '', component: AppComponent},
   {path : 'products', loadChildren : () => import('./product/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule) }

];

@NgModule({
    imports : [RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES, {enableTracing: true})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingMoudle {}
```

---

**AppModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {CommonHttpService} from './http-services/common-http.service';
import { ProductModule } from './product/product.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule, //provides HttpClient service that can be 
                     // injected into component & services
   
   // ProductModule
  ],
  providers: [CommonHttpService], // provide the HttpService globally
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

---

**ProductRoutingModule**

```
import { RouterModule ,Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';
import { ProductItemComponent } from './product-item/product-item.component';


const ROUTES : Routes = [
    {path: '', component: ProductComponent},
    {path: ':id', component: ProductItemComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports : [RouterModule.forChild(ROUTES)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class ProductRoutingModule{}
```

---

**ProductModule**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';


import { ProductItemComponent } from './product-item/product-item.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product.component';
import {CommonHttpService} from '../http-services/common-http.service';
import { ProductRoutingModule } from './product.routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ProductComponent,
    ProductItemComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ProductRoutingModule
  ],
  providers : [CommonHttpService] // Make HttpService available for product components
                                  // and its child components.
})
export class ProductModule { }
```

---

**app.component.html**

```
<!-- Toolbar -->
<div class="toolbar" role="banner">
  <span>Welcome</span>
</div>

<div class="content" role="main">
  <!-- Highlight Card -->
  <div class="card highlight-card card-small">
    <span>{{ title }} app is running!</span>
  </div>

  <div class="card-container">
  </div>
  <div class="card-container">
  </div>
  <!-- Terminal -->
  <div class="terminal" >
  </div>
  <!-- Links -->
  <div class="card-container">
  </div>
  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
      Love Angular?
  </footer>
</div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

**Error**: main.ts:6 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NG04002: ***Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'products'***
Error: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'products'
at Recognizer.noMatchError (router.mjs:3655:16)

---

Versions:

- Angular CLI: 16.2.0
  Node: 16.18.0
  Package Manager: npm 8.19.2

Angular: 16.2.0
animations, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

| Package | Version |
| --- | --- |
| @angular-devkit/architect | 0.1602.0 |
| @angular-devkit/build-angular | 16.2.0 |
| @angular-devkit/core | 16.2.0 |
| @angular-devkit/schematics | 16.2.0 |
| @schematics/angular | 16.2.0 |
| rxjs | 7.8.1 |
| typescript | 5.1.6 |
| zone.js | 0.13.1 |

I am trying to access ProductComponent from ProductModule using lazy loading from root module(AppModule) using separate routing module AppRoutingModule for cleaner code.

Products route is loading successfully, if I directly import product into AppModule but failing if I use lazy loading route concepts.
I don't understand why this is not working and what exactly am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Import products module to main module
2. Crete a products module and products routing module
3. Import products routing module to products module

[image]
[image: main routing module]
[image: prodcuts module]
[image: products routing module]
[image]
[image]

Comment: If we import ProductModule directly into AppModule import property. Will lazy loading of Product Module still works?

Comment: No, For lazyloading don't import the Products module in main module.